# Object Barriers in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am a beginner at coding but I am trying to make a flash rpg type game. I have a barrier around my game and a walking person (manmc). I have been watching videos/reading articles on how to make object barriers but I can not seem to get the coding right without getting errors. I am trying to get my character to stop when he hits a tree. The tree is coded as (treer1_MC). I only tried to code it on the down press but it does nothing and it causes the character to not be able to walk back up.

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Stage;

manmc.gotoAndStop ("Stand Front Frame");

var rightPressed:Boolean = new Boolean(false);
var leftPressed:Boolean = new Boolean(false);
var upPressed:Boolean = new Boolean(false);
var downPressed:Boolean = new Boolean(false);
var manSpeed:Number = 3;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop);

function keyDownHandler (keyEvent:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if(keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
    {
        rightPressed = true;
    }
    else if(keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
    {
        leftPressed = true;
    }
    else if(keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
    {
        upPressed = true;
    }
    else if(keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
    {
        downPressed = true;
    }
}

function keyUpHandler (keyEvent:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if(keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
    {
        rightPressed = false;
        manmc.gotoAndStop("Stand Right Frame");
    }
    else if(keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
    {
        leftPressed = false;
        manmc.gotoAndStop("Stand Left Frame");
    }
    else if(keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
    {
        upPressed = false;
        manmc.gotoAndStop("Stand Back Frame");
    }
    else if(keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
    {
        downPressed = false;
        manmc.gotoAndStop("Stand Front Frame");
    }
}

function gameLoop(loopEvent:Event):void
{
    if(rightPressed)
    {
        if(manmc.x < 1050)
        {
            manmc.x += manSpeed;
        }
        manmc.gotoAndStop("Walk Right Frame");
    }
    else if(leftPressed)
    {
        if (manmc.x > 145)
        {
            manmc.x -= manSpeed;
        }
        manmc.gotoAndStop("Walk Left Frame");
    } 
    else if(downPressed)
    {
        if(manmc.y < 780)
        {
        manmc.y += manSpeed;
        }
        manmc.gotoAndStop("Walk Front Frame");
    }
        if (manmc.hitTest(treer1_MC))
    {
            trace("leftHit");
            manmc._x += 3;

    }
    else if(upPressed)
    {
        if(manmc.y > 145)
        {
            manmc.y -= manSpeed;
        }
        manmc.gotoAndStop("Walk Back Frame");
    }
}
```

This is the coding a tutorial said to use. Any suggestions?

```
if (manmc.hitTest(treer1_MC))
        trace("leftHit");
        manmc._x += 3;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just because the declaration of the collision condition is outside of your "downPress" condition:

```
 else if(downPressed)
{
    if(manmc.y < 780)
    {
    manmc.y += manSpeed;
    }
    manmc.gotoAndStop("Walk Front Frame");
}
    if (manmc.hitTest(treer1_MC))
{
        trace("leftHit");
        manmc._x += 3;

}
```

indentation problems :), the right way should be:

```
 else if(downPressed)
{
    if(manmc.y < 780)
    {
    manmc.y += manSpeed;
    }
    manmc.gotoAndStop("Walk Front Frame");

    if (manmc.hitTest(treer1_MC))
    {
        trace("leftHit");
        manmc._x += 3;
    }
}
```

I hope it helps ;)

Edit:

**manmc.hitTest(treer1_MC)**

should be:

**manmc.hitTestObject(treer1_MC)**

Because the function: hitTest() is a AS2 function, on AS3 whe have: hitTestPoint() and hitTestObject() ;)

Comment: Still gave an error:( "TypeError: Error #1006: hitTest is not a function.
 at Start_fla::MainTimeline/gameLoop()"

Comment: Oh! and one more thing:

manmc.hitTest(treer1_MC)

should be:

manmc. hitTestObject(treer1_MC)

Comment: @SamA Welcome to Stackoverflow! If this answer solved your problem, please click the tick on the left of it. This allows other people that have the same problem identify this as the accepted working answer. Please also [Take the Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) it will help you understand how StackOverflow (SO for short) works.